# Map larger number to 1-4 in 25000 steps

Tags: javascript, node.js, math

Some split testing shall be done on a website.
There are 4 versions of the website and I have the total visitor count.
Every 25000 visitors I want to increment the version by 1.
If the version reaches 4 it should start with 1 again.

I need a function that maps the visitor count to one of the variants as described above. 
Input visitor count, output variant.

```
1-25000 => 1
25001 - 50000 => 2
50001 - 75000 => 3
75001 - 100000 => 4
100001 - 125000 => 1
etc.
```

The only solution I can come up with would be to pre-build an object with with keys 1 - 10 million and the according variant as the value but this can't be an ideal solution.

Comment: How about a simple if-else ladder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Math.floor()` and division here, then use the modulo arithmetic to cycle.

```
const visitorChunk = Math.floor((visitorCount-1) / 25000); //counts up one every 25000 visitors
let siteVersion = (visitorChunk % 4); //cycles from 0-3
siteVersion++; //cycles from 1-4
```